# How do I convert Type.registerNamespace to TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to convert some of our javascript to TypeScript but I don't know if typescript supports the namespaces.  We have code that looks like this:

```
/// <reference name="MicrosoftAjax.js"/>
Type.registerNamespace("MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane");

MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane = function (element)
{
...
}
MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane.prototype =
{
...
}
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to specify namespaces in typescript that include periods?  We reference those same names in our C# classes like:

```
[assembly: WebResource("MyNamespace.FloatingErrorPane.js", "text/javascript")]
ScriptControlDescriptor descriptor = new ScriptControlDescriptor("MyNamspace.Controls.Floating
```

ErrorPane", this.ClientID);

Comment: Did you leave something after `.prototype`? Or are you trying to inherit from a Superclass? (If want to inherit from a super class you'd do what @Sohnee was saying, and just add `export class FloatingErrorPane extends YourSuperClassHere { ` <-- adding that extends part

Answer (score 4):

You can use nested modules and classes to get a namespace style syntax.

This first example matches the example in your question...

```
module MyNamespace {
    export module Controls {
        export class FloatingErrorPane {
            constructor(private element: HTMLElement) {
            }
        }
    }
}

var errorPane = new MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane(myElement);
```

You can declare modules across multiple files if you want to, so a second file can add to `MyNamespace` by declaring it again...

```
module MyNamespace {
    export module Messaging {
        export class MessageHandler {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to nest modules. You can just specify: module MyNamespace.Controls { ...  }

Comment: Good observation - nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the . notation to create nested namespaces, e.g.

```
module MyNamespace.Controls {
    export class FloatingErrorPane {
        constructor(element: HTMLElement) {
        }
    }
}

var errorPane = new MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane(myElement);
```

Or you can use the syntax as shown by Sohnee where you declare modules successively. You cannot define a class or function directly in this way, though. So this is not valid:

```
MyNamespace.Controls.FloatingErrorPane = function() { ... }
```